Under what conditions might the androidx.startup.InitializationProvider not be invoked, even if it is present in manifest
We are setting up appium tests with espresso driver for our project. And test code works fine (for about a minute) until it invokes WorkManager.getInstance()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(WorkManagerImpl.java:170)
        at androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance(WorkManager.java:184)

Usual launch is going well without any crashes at that point.
Merged manifest of the app sets it's initialization in  tag:
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.cannondale.app.androidx-startup">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

To eliminate the issue I added additional dependencies to espresso server apk and it's merge manifest also has these providers:
<provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="io.appium.espressoserver.test.androidx-startup">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

But the issue still exists. There is similar bug in espresso driver issue tracker.
https://github.com/appium/appium-espresso-driver/issues/793
And now I am wondering why initialization code wasn't invoked. What conditions in instrumentation tests might lead to such issues?
